# How to make a local server in nodejs accessible from internet

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, vps

I am trying to develop a server using nodejs that can be accessed through the internet without a public IP address. can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the things were simple. we just have to initiate a socket connection between local and remote servers. the local server should ask for a connection to the remote and the remote should keep the identifier of this local server. after keeping it, the two could now communicate easily through event.